# db class in pdo, prepare and execute dont work, why?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

trying to setup my db class on php, following an youtube tutorial, in the tutorial it runs fine, but on my machine "$this->_query->execute()" returns false

here is my class:

```
class DB {
private static $_instance = null;
private $_pdo, $_query, $_error = false, $_results, $_count = 0, $_lastInsertID = '';

private function __construct() {
    try{
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dname=database','root','');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function get_instance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function query($sql,$params = []){
    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
        $x = 1;
        var_dump($params);
        if(count($params)){
            foreach ($params as $param){
                $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()){
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            $this->_lastInsertID = $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
        }else{
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

and here the php file that calls the function:

```
require_once 'classes/DB.php';

$db = DB::get_instance();

$contact = 
['Ewerton','Marschalk','Ewerton@hotmail.com','44444444444','5555555555555'];


 $db->query("INSERT INTO contacts (`fname`,`lname`,`email`,`cell_phone`,`home_phone`) values (?,?,?,?,?)",$contact);
```

why this is no working?

Comment: In its default mode, PDO errors silently. I would always recommend configuring it to throw exceptions, which would be more obvious when it dies with a fatal error (`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`)  Use `$this->_pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after creating the object.

Comment: Do you know that you can simply pass the array of parameters as an argument to `execute()`, so you don't need the `bindValue()` loop?

Comment: even passing direcly, it returns false on the execute, following Michael instructions now i have an error to work with...
"Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected"

Comment: You have a typo: `dname=database` should be `dbname=database`.

Comment: looks like was missing an "b" in dbname... hell, 3 hours lost because of this... thank you guys, problem solved